# How to map an Observable to another type of Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have this

```
  public getRouteData(): BehaviorSubject<string[]> {
     return this.routeData;
  }
```

I wan to map this to an Observable of `{name: r}` where `r` is an item in the `string[]`

```
public gridData: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

I would like to take the `string[]` and map to array of object `{name: r}` where `r` is item of array, so that I can bind the object array to the grid.

Somehow not able to sequence or the syntax right.

Tried `getRouteData().map(r => ({name: r})).subscribe(r => this.gridData.next(r));` but this is not correct as I am ending up with `{name:string[]}` instead of `[{name:string}]`

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: You misunderstand how observables work. If your observable is handling `string[]`, that's what you get as the parameter to `map`. If your observable is emitting one string at a time, it should be a `BehaviourSubject<string>`, not `BehaviorSubject<string[]>`. Then your map parameter will get a `string`, not a `string[]`.

Comment: So instead of an `Observable<string[]>` you want an `Observable<{ name: string }[]>`?

Comment: Daniel W Strimpel  - yes that is what I needed. then map is not right ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you are looking for this:

```js
getRouteData() // => Observable<string[]>
    .map(r => r.map(v => ({name: v}))) // => Observable<{ name: string }[]>
    .subscribe(r => this.gridData.next(r));
```

The outer `map(...)` is iterating over each value emitted from your observable. So, `r` is of type `string[]`.

The inner `map(...)` is iterating over each element in your `r` array and converting the `string` to the `{ name: string }` type.